# AWS DynamoDB JS sdk get all Items by using only partition key

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query my dynamoDB which has a partition and a sort key, the partition key is an id and the sort key is a generated timestamp.
The problem is that it won't work when giving only partition key as parameter which is what I need to do, here is the error :
**"The provided key element does not match the schema"**

```
case "GET /items/{id}":
        body = await dynamo.send(
          new GetCommand({
            TableName: tableName,
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
        );
        body = body.Item;
        break;
```

And here is a sample data :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: you cannot query by sort key only, need the partition key and optionally use the sort key https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Comment: an option can be modifying the squema, creating a global secondary index, or use a scan operation (this can be expensive and slower since "scan" the whole table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need to use a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) command, which allows you to specify only the Partition key, and optionally conditions on the Sort key. A query returns 0 or multiple items.

A GetItem must give full equality on Partition and Sort key, which is why you were unable to do so. A GetItem returns 0 or 1 item.

```
const params = {
  KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :id",
  TableName: tableName,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":id": event.pathParameters.id
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#id": "id"
  }
};

  try {
    const data = await dynamo.send(new QueryCommand(params));
    console.log(data.Items);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```